# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'kendoDatePicker'

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I added a datepicker kendo control in my view. When I executed out the MVC application it gave me following error in the console window.Is there something wrong with my jquery?

[image]

Comment: post your code so we help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code, and your javascript includes.

You likely either didn't include the Kendo javascript file in the page, or included jQuery after Kendo instead of the other way around.